# Consulta en PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Amigos me podrían ayudar a revisar por favor que es lo que tengo mal al realizar la siguiente consulta, los datos no me los esta trayendo.

[image: Tablas de la consulta con sus respectivas relaciones]

Código de la consulta en PHP de las tablas

```
function read_u(){
                    // read query
                    $query = "SELECT variable_dispositivo.id,variable_dispositivo.factor_cambio,variable_dispositivo.tiempo_cambio,variable_dispositivo.v_min,variable_dispositivo.v_max,limite.nombre as limite, variable_limite.valor as valor_limite,variable_limite.id as limite_id,variable.color, variable.nomenclatura as variable,intercepto.intercepto, intercepto.pendiente,unidad.valor as unidad,variable.nombre FROM " . $this->table_name."
                        INNER JOIN (SELECT * from (SELECT MAX(fecha) as fecha,ajuste.intercepto,ajuste.pendiente,variable_dispositivo.id as variable_dispositivo FROM variable_dispositivo INNER JOIN ajuste on ajuste.variable_dispositivo=variable_dispositivo.id WHERE variable_dispositivo.dispositivo=:dispositivo GROUP BY ajuste.id DESC)  as t group by variable_dispositivo DESC) as intercepto on intercepto.variable_dispositivo=variable_dispositivo.id
                          LEFT JOIN variable_limite on variable_dispositivo.id=variable_limite.variable_dispositivo
                          LEFT JOIN limite on variable_limite.limite=limite.id
                          LEFT JOIN unidad_variable on variable_dispositivo.id=unidad_variable.variable_dispositivo
                          LEFT JOIN unidad on unidad.id=unidad_variable.unidad
                          LEFT JOIN  variable on variable_dispositivo.variable=variable.id
                          WHERE variable_dispositivo.dispositivo=:dispositivo ORDER BY variable_dispositivo.id DESC";
                    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
                    // sanitize
                    $this->dispositivo=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->dispositivo));
                    // bind values
                    $stmt->bindParam(":dispositivo", $this->dispositivo);
                    // execute query
                    $stmt->execute();
                    return $stmt;
    }
```

Resulta que al llamar la función de la consulta que es (function read_u) en el siguiente código me esta saltando al error array("message" => "No variable_dispositivo found.")osea no me esta entrando a la condición if porque no me llega el ID dispositivo, para que por favor me ayuden a revisar si la consulta que estoy realizando esta bien.

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

// get database connection
include_once '../config/database.php';

// instantiate variable_dispositivo object
include_once '../objects/variable_dispositivo.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$variable_dispositivo= new variable_dispositivo($db);

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$variable_dispositivo->dispositivo=$data->dispositivo;
// query variable_dispositivos
$stmt = $variable_dispositivo->read_u();
$num = $stmt->rowCount();
// check if more than 0 record found
$variable_dispositivo_arr=array();
if($num>0){
    // retrieve our table contents
    // fetch() is faster than fetchAll()
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770630/pdofetchall-vs-pdofetch-in-a-loop
    $c=0;
    $di=0;
    $unidades=array();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        // extract row
        // this will make $row["name"] to
        // just $name only
        extract($row);
        if($di!=$id){
            $variable_dispositivo_item_arr=array(
                            "id"=>$id,
                             "nombre"=>$nombre,
                             "variable"=>$variable,
                             "color"=>$color,
                             "ecuacion"=>array("m"=>$pendiente,"b"=>$intercepto),
                             "unidades"=>$unidades,
                             "factor_cambio"=>$factor_cambio,
                             "tiempo_cambio"=>$tiempo_cambio,
                             "val_max"=>$v_max,
                             "val_min"=>$v_min,
                             "limites"=>$limites,
                             "limis"=>$lims
                        );
                        $variable_dispositivo_item_arr["unidades"][]=$unidad;
                        $variable_dispositivo_item_arr["limites"][$limite]=$valor_limite;
                        $variable_dispositivo_item_arr["limis"][$limite]=array("valor"=>$valor_limite,"id"=>$limite_id);

                        $unidades=array();
                        $limites=array();
                        $lims=array();
            $variable_dispositivo_arr[$c]=$variable_dispositivo_item_arr;
            $di=$id;
            $c++;
        }else{
            if (!in_array($unidad, $$variable_dispositivo_arr[$c-1]["unidades"])) {
                $variable_dispositivo_arr[$c-1]["unidades"][]=$unidad;
                $variable_dispositivo_arr[$c-1]["unidades"]=array_unique($variable_dispositivo_arr[$c-1]["unidades"]);
            }
            if (!in_array($limite, $$variable_dispositivo_arr[$c-1]["limites"])) {
                                $variable_dispositivo_arr[$c-1]["limites"][$limite]=$valor_limite;

            }
            if (!in_array(array("valor"=>$valor_limite,"id"=>$limite_id), $$variable_dispositivo_arr[$c-1]["limis"])) {
                $variable_dispositivo_arr[$c-1]["limis"][$limite]=array("valor"=>$valor_limite,"id"=>$limite_id);

            }
            
        }
        
    }
    // set response code - 200 OK
    http_response_code(200);
    // show users data in json format
    echo json_encode($variable_dispositivo_arr);
}else{
    // set response code - 404 Not found
    http_response_code(404);
    // tell the user no variable_dispositivos found
    echo json_encode(
    array("message" => "No variable_dispositivo found.")
    );
}
    // no variable_dispositivo found will be here
?>
```

De antemano Gracias

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende, ¿qué debemos revisar?, ¿da algún error?, ¿entrega algún dato?, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Es que al realizar la consulta de los datos, no me esta trayendo los datos de las tablas.

Comment: Entonces como recomendé lee [ask], edita y deja en la misma claro el problema por favor, por otro lado requerimos de un [mcve] de otro modo con lo que provees no creo que se pueda hacer mucho

Comment: No trae nada? Esperas un resultado y sale otra cosa? Hay algo en los logs de PHP? Por favor, edita la pregunta y trata de ser un poco más específico.

Comment: ¿Has depurado algo? Cada vez estoy más convencido de que es fundamental aprender a depurar el código (ahorrarás mucho tiempo). Otro gran problema de muchos programadores es que escriben código pensando en un mundo color de rosa donde no hay problemas. ¿Qué control de errores hay en tu función? No hay ninguno. La consulta puede fallar, puede no haber conexión, puede devolver cero filas. ¿Dónde estás controlando eso? Tu tarea como programador es también controlar los errores y dar una respuesta adecuada a los mismos. Si hubieras programado así sabrías lo que ocurre ahora y por qué falla.

Comment: Por otra parte, si usas consultas preparadas, no tienes que sanear nada, de eso se encarga la consulta preparada. Conviene no abusar de las funciones.

Comment: Miren amigos, ya agregue el código que me faltaba y edite la pregunta espero me haya hecho entender y agradezco su colaboración.

Comment: Pues lo dicho. 1. ¿Estás seguro de que hay conexión? Deberías controlar eso. 2. El manual dice que no se debería confiar en `rowCount()` para consutlas de tipo SELECT, porque en algunos SGBD no funciona bien. Considera cambiar la lógica, verificando todos los posibles errores dentro de `read_u()` y llenando los datos allí, y devolviendo los datos o un objeto con una clave `error` en caso de que haya error.  Así, verificarías el resultado de la llamada en vez de usar `rowCount()` ... Tienes una lógica mal montada en ese punto y deberías corregirla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes establecer un control en la función y devolver los datos desde ella. Si hubiera error, la función devolverá un array con una clave `error`, si no, devolverá los datos.

La función quedaría así:

```
function read_u(){
                    // read query
    $query = "SELECT variable_dispositivo.id,variable_dispositivo.factor_cambio,variable_dispositivo.tiempo_cambio,variable_dispositivo.v_min,variable_dispositivo.v_max,limite.nombre as limite, variable_limite.valor as valor_limite,variable_limite.id as limite_id,variable.color, variable.nomenclatura as variable,intercepto.intercepto, intercepto.pendiente,unidad.valor as unidad,variable.nombre FROM " . $this->table_name."
                        INNER JOIN (SELECT * from (SELECT MAX(fecha) as fecha,ajuste.intercepto,ajuste.pendiente,variable_dispositivo.id as variable_dispositivo FROM variable_dispositivo INNER JOIN ajuste on ajuste.variable_dispositivo=variable_dispositivo.id WHERE variable_dispositivo.dispositivo=:dispositivo GROUP BY ajuste.id DESC)  as t group by variable_dispositivo DESC) as intercepto on intercepto.variable_dispositivo=variable_dispositivo.id
                          LEFT JOIN variable_limite on variable_dispositivo.id=variable_limite.variable_dispositivo
                          LEFT JOIN limite on variable_limite.limite=limite.id
                          LEFT JOIN unidad_variable on variable_dispositivo.id=unidad_variable.variable_dispositivo
                          LEFT JOIN unidad on unidad.id=unidad_variable.unidad
                          LEFT JOIN  variable on variable_dispositivo.variable=variable.id
                          WHERE variable_dispositivo.dispositivo=:dispositivo ORDER BY variable_dispositivo.id DESC";
    if ($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query) ) {
        $stmt->bindParam(":dispositivo", $this->dispositivo);
        $stmt->execute();
        $mData=array();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $mData[]=$row;
        }
        #Devolverá los datos si hay, o una clave error
        return !empty($mData) ? $mData : array ('error'=>'No se encontraron datos');
    } else {
        #Devolverá una clave error porque falló la preparación
        return array('error'=>'Revise la sintaxis de la consulta SQL');
        
    }                
}
```

Y en el contexto:

```
#^Tu código anterior ....
#Aquí partimos de la verificación de la conexión
$db = $database->getConnection();

#Verificar que hay conexión
if ($db) {
    $variable_dispositivo= new variable_dispositivo($db);
    
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $variable_dispositivo->dispositivo=$data->dispositivo;
    // query variable_dispositivos
    $mData = $variable_dispositivo->read_u();
    #Verificamos si hay clave error
    if(isset($mData['error'])){
        #Poner un header si fuera preciso, aquí hay error
        echo json_encode($mData);
    } else {
        /*
            Mucha atención aquí:
            En este bloque leerías los datos y harías lo que requieras
            teniendo en cuenta que esto no es necesario
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            Ya los datos se obtuvieron en read_u 
            y fueron retornados como array asociativo
            por tanto los tienes en $mData
            sería cuestión entonces de leer $mData
            Incorpora aquí las variables que haga falta
        */

        http_response_code(200);
        // show users data in json format
        #Se supone que $variable_dispositivo_arr
        #será llenado leyendo $mData
        echo json_encode($variable_dispositivo_arr);        
    }
        
}else{
    #Poner un header si fuera preciso
    echo json_encode(array('error'=>'No hay conexión a la BD.'));
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @A. Cedano , me sirvió mucho y aprendí.